# Dealing with post requests and tokens while testing a React application with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

This is my first time working with jest and react. I created an application that requires a user to be authenticated to access certain resources.

I created the following function in the Login component for authentication that makes an axios call to the server-

```
    const loginUtil = async() => {

        const res = await axios
            .post("http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate", {
                username,
                password,
            });

        console.log(res.data);
        
        if (res.data.jwt) {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res.data));
        } else {
            throw new Error();
        }
        return JSON.stringify(res.data);
    }

    return loginUtil();
};
```

I wrote the following two Jest test case for the component -

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { rest } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from '../Login'
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'

const fakeUserResponse = {jwt: 'fake_user_token',user : {
    username : 'jane',
    pasword : 'pass',
    role : 'user',
    id : 'ftrb3344grr'
}}
const server = setupServer(
  rest.post('http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json(fakeUserResponse))
  }),
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen())

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
  });

afterEach(() => {
    server.resetHandlers()
    window.localStorage.removeItem('user')
  })

afterAll(() => server.close())

test('token is saved correctly', async() => {
    
    render(<Login />)
  
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/username/i), {
      target: {value: 'jane'},
    })

    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/i), {
      target: {value: 'pass'}
    })

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/login/i))

    expect(localStorage.getItem('user')).toEqual(fakeUserResponse)
})
```

The first test case passes but the second doesn't. I'm also getting the following error -

[Error message in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZUEb.png)

```
 FAIL  src/components/__tests__/Login.test.js (6.919 s)
  ● token is saved correctly

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: {"jwt": "fake_user_token", "user": {"id": "ftrb3344grr", "pasword": "pass", "role": "user", "username": "jane"}}
    Received: null

      61 |     fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/login/i))
      62 |
    > 63 |     expect(localStorage.getItem('user')).toEqual(fakeUserResponse)
         |                                          ^
      64 | })
      65 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests__/Login.test.js:63:42)


  ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "{
      jwt: 'fake_user_token',
      user: {
        username: 'jane',
        pasword: 'pass',
        role: 'user',
        id: 'ftrb3344grr'
      }
    }".

      16 |         } else {
      17 |             throw new Error();
    > 18 |         }
         |          ^
      19 |         return JSON.stringify(res.data);
      20 |     }
      21 |

      at BufferedConsole.log (node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js:197:10)
      at loginUtil (src/service/authService.js:18:13)
```

What this tells me is the response data is correctly sent by the mock server but for some reason the data can't be logged into the console. The test stops giving expected results beyond that.

Any kind of help regarding why this is happening would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just mock local storage, for your use. Here is an example for it.

```
//Storage Mock
const storageMock = () => {
 let storage = {};

 return {
   setItem:(key, value) => {
    storage[key] = value || '';
   },
   getItem: (key) => {
    return storage[key] || null;
   },
   removeItem: (key) => {
    delete storage[key];
   },
   clear: function() {
    store = {};
   },
   getLength: () => {
    return Object.keys(storage).length;
   },
   key: function(i) {
    const keys = Object.keys(storage);
    return keys[i] || null;
   }
 };
}
```

And the you do something like:

```
// mock the localStorage
window.localStorage = storageMock();
// mock the sessionStorage
window.sessionStorage = storageMock();
```

Comment: I tried using this in my test script. But apparantly the test finishes its execution before the result is returned.